# Complex urls in mvc views - who's responsible to construct them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

Lets say I need to create a search page. On that page there are:

- Complex search filter with many search parameters (param1, param2, ..., paramN)
- A list of result items
- A pager
- A layout switch links (list or table view)

I pass a view model from my action to the view with information about current values of search parameters (from url) and some "guessed" parameters which does not came from url directly (for example, if user does not specify region we can guess it from his ip).

Now, for each link in the pager I'll have to write a code like this

```
<a href="@Url.Action(null, new { page = n, param1, param2, ..., paramN, region })">...
```

For layout switch links I'll have to write similar but different code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(null, new { page = currentPage, mode = DisplayModes.List, param1, param2, ..., paramN, region })">list</a>
<a href="@Url.Action(null, new { page = currentPage, mode = DisplayModes.Table, param1, param2, ..., paramN, region })">table</a>
```

What I don't like is that how lots of code leaked to view. It's hard to maintain and hard to test.

So I'm wandering is constructing url for such complex pages is the responsibility of view or an action?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `RouteValueDictionary` to build query part of url.

In the action code I would fill parameters and put in ViewBag:

```
var routes = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
routes.Add("param1", "value1");
routes.Add("param2", "value2");

ViewBag.routes = routes;
```

And then construct my links in the View like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("List", null, (RouteValueDictionary)ViewBag.routes)
```

Or if you prefer using Url.Action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(null, ViewBag.routes)">List</a>
```

And yes, complex logic should be in the action, so it's unit-testable. Less logic you have in the View - better.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that I need different parameters for pager and display modes urls.

Comment: How is that the problem? Create 2 RouteValueDictionary objects, one for each Url.

Comment: Then it's just better to construct url inside action altogether - those custom route values has no use outside a very specific urls they were created for.

Comment: That's too much display logic in the Action for my taste, but do as you prefer.